# Jquery click event not returning anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, alert

My jquery is not alerting anything when I click the button with the id decrease. This is my code. I am using external js file.

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#decrease').click(function() {
        var beforeIncrement = $('#amt').val();
        alert(beforeIncrement);
    }))
```

I tried doing this and it is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Ready");
})
```

This is the html code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center d-flex">
     <button id="decrease" class="btn btn-warning">-</button>
         <input type="number" id="amt" value="1"/>
     <button id="increase" class="btn btn-warning">+</button>
</div>
```

what's wrong with my first code snippet?

Comment: Would you try `$('#decrease').on('click', function(e) {})`?

Comment: could you display the htm code?

Comment: I have added the html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you pass to `ready()` needs to be a **function**.

In your first example, you are passing the return value of `$('#decrease').click(...)`.

This means that `$('#decrease').click(...)` has to be evaluated **immediately**, so it is looking for `#decrease` before the DOM is ready and the element doesn't exist yet.

`ready()` then ignores the value you pass to it because it isn't a function.

---

Wrap the call to `$('#decrease').click(...)` in a function, just as you did for `alert(...)` in the second example.

---

You also have a missing `);` at the end but I'm guessing that just got cut off when you transcribed your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$('#decrease').on('click', function(){
        var beforeIncrement = $('#amt').val();
        alert(beforeIncrement);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the right html syntax, the right syntax for your js script is:
(you have to use a function for document.ready):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#decrease').click(function() {
      var beforeIncrement = $('#amt').val();
      alert(beforeIncrement);
    });
});
```

you could use the shorthand syntax:

```
$(function() {
    $('#decrease').click(function() {
      var beforeIncrement = $('#amt').val();
      alert(beforeIncrement);
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't know there is a shorthand syntax. Thanks! The problem was that I loaded the script before the html is parsed...